# Getting the EPOCH time for a custom date values in bash

Tags: bash

I need to write a bash function to return the EPOCH time for a custom date, in the future.

I use date and time in the formats;

```
date=20130122 # i.e. 2013 01 22
time=1455     # i.e. 14:55
```

Can I get the EPOCH time with these values?

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
date -d "$date $time" +%s
```

Would work in GNU date.

For BSD `date` (included with Mac OS X), the command would be

```
date -j -f "%Y%m%d %H%M" "$date $time" +%s
```

(`-f` is needed to parse your date and time as given; the default format would require "012214552013" to specify the same time)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:

```
date --date "20130122 1455" +%s
```

This will give you the date in epoch.

Or if you use variables, just replace the date and time like this:

```
d=20130122
t=1455
date --date "$d $t" +%s
```

And try to avoid using "date" and "time" as variable names, since they easily could be misunderstood as commands (they are both valid commands). This to increase readability.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was after, but the other guy has the variables.

Comment: Yea, I've updated the answer a couple of times. First version was just quick'n'dirty to get you on the right track. :)

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this one. In BASH 3.2 I get an 'invalid date' error. Should be:

```
date -d "2013-01-22 14:55" +%s
```